# Como configurar o AutoIncrement do PostgreSQL usando o EF Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Tenho um mapeamento de uma tabela (Entity Framework Core 2.0) no qual o campo Id precisa ser AutoIncrement.

O problema é que o PostgreSQL está iniciando com valor alto e muitas vezes fica saltando para sequências muito altas, tipo, incrementando de 10 em 10.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Gostaria que fosse iniciado com 0 e fosse autoincrementando.

```
(
public class ProfissaoMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Profissao>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Profissao> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Profissao");

        builder.HasKey(p => new {p.Id});

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ProfissaoId")
            .HasColumnType("integer")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.Descricao)
           .HasColumnName("Descricao")
           .HasColumnType("character varying(50)")
           .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.PadraoSistema)
          .HasColumnName("PadraoSistema")
          .HasColumnType("boolean");

    }
}
```

Comment: Por que tem isso `builder.HasKey(p => new {p.Id});`? Não deveria ser `builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);`? Não deve ter relação com o problema descrito, mas estranhei.

Comment: Uma vez, segui um exemplo na net que ensinava a usar o new... Funciona das duas maneiras @hkotsubo rsrsssrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O PostgreSQL nao e o problema, e sim essa classe que ".ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo()"

> Quando o intervalo está esgotado, um novo intervalo é alocado. Em
>   termos práticos, isso usa uma sequência que é incrementada por algum
>   valor grande (100 por padrão), permitindo que o aplicativo insira 100
>   linhas de forma autônoma.

em outras palavras se tiver alguma tipo de timeout o ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo vai pular algumas casas do id e para inserir.

Eu tenho projeto generico vc pode dar uma olhada e alterar o seu projeto, estou usando o framework mas e facil de alterar para o core, caso queira: [Postgres Generic Repository](https://github.com/hudsonphilipe/postgresGenericRepository)

Comment: Obrigado @HudsonPH! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a documentação do `Entity Framework Core`, você pode utilizar o seguinte

`.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();`

```
builder.Property(p => p.Id)
        .ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo();
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        .IsRequired();
```

Para mais informações segue: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties